# validate multiple drop down lists with textboxes

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, asp-classic

i have a form wherein there are multiple drop down lists...if i am to validate a single drop down list my code works fine...

using this code:

```
                if ($("select[id*=drpR]").val() == "Choose Reseller") {
                    $("#lblmessage").html("Please choose Reseller!");
                    return false;//To prevent the form from submitting.
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
```

but when i have to validate a form with 3 drop down lists and many textbox my jquery doesnt work..now where will i put this code block in order to function properly for my validation..or is there a better solution to my problem..

here's what i have for my jquery:

```
                 jQuery("#Merchant_Registration").validate({
                    rules: {
                        drpT: {
                            required: {
                                depends: function (element) {
                                    var flag = true;
                                    if ($("select[id*=drpT]").val() == "Choose Type") {
                                        //alert("Please select Merchant type");
                                        $("#lbldrpT").append("Please choose Type!");
                                        flag = false;//To prevent the form from submitting.
                                    } else {
                                        $("#lbldrpT").empty();
                                    }
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        LastName: "required",
                        FirstName: "required",
                        EmailAd: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true,
                            minlength: 8
                        },
                        CompanyN: "required",
                        url: "required",
                        drpI: {
                            required: {
                                depends: function (element) {
                                    var flag = true;
                                    if ($("select[id*=drpI]").val() == "Choose Industry") {
                                        $("#lbldrpI").append("Please choose Industry!");
                                        flag = false;//To prevent the form from submitting.
                                    } else {
                                        $("#lbldrpI").empty();
                                    }
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        HNumber: "required",
                        stADR: "required",
                        town: "required",
                        city: "required",
                        state: "required",
                        Zcode: "required",
                        drpC: {
                            required: {
                                depends: function (element) {
                                    var flag = true;
                                    if ($("select[id*=drpC]").val() == "Choose Country") {
                                        $("#lbldrpC").append("Please choose Coutnry!");
                                        flag = false;//To prevent the form from submitting.
                                    } else {
                                        $("#lbldrpC").empty();
                                    }
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        TNumber: "required",
                        FNumber: "required"
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        xval = true;
                    },
                    messages: {
                        FirstName: "Please enter your first name",
                        LastName: "Please enter your first name",
                        EmailAd: "Please enter a valid email address",
                        CompanyN: "Please enter company name",
                        url: "Please enter URL",
                        HNumber: "Please enter house number",
                        stADR: "Please enter street",
                        town: "Please enter town",
                        city: "Please enter city or municipality",
                        state: "Please enter state or province",
                        Zcode: "Please enter zip code",
                        TNumber: "Please enter telephone number",
                        FNumber: "Please enter fax number"
                    }
                });

                $("select").change(function () {
                    $("#lbl" + $(this).attr("id")).empty();
                })

                if (!jQuery("#Merchant_Registration").valid()) {
                    flag = false;
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
                if (flag) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
```

here's my for my mark up:

```
            <div id="step2" class="formwiz">
                <h4>Step 2: Personal Information</h4>
                <p>
                <label>Select Type:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpT" runat="server" Width="160" class="required"></asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Label ID="lbldrpT" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>Firstname:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server" MaxLength ="50"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>LastName:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server" MaxLength ="50"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>Email Address</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="EmailAd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
               </p>

                <p>
                <label>Company Name:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="CompanyN" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>Website URL:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="url" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>Select Industry:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpI" runat="server" Width="160" class="required"></asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Label ID="lbldrpI" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>House Number:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="HNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>Street Address:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="stADR" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>Town:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="town" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>City:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="city" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>State:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="state" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>Zip Code:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="Zcode" runat="server" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>Country:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpC" runat="server" Width="160" class="required"></asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Label ID="lbldrpC" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>Telephone Number:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TNumber" runat="server" MaxLength="11"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>Fax Number:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="FNumber" runat="server" MaxLength="11"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>
            </div>
```

please help...

Comment: You've got `return true` in all the 3 `if` blocks. Which means that if the first one validates the rest of the code will not execute. Try to `return true` once when all the 3 `if` blocks are validated.

Comment: it's working now...thank you..but i have another question...when i click next, the page only shows the validation for the drop down lists...not the textboxes...how can i resolve that..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var flag = true;
if ($("select[id*=drpT]").val() == "Choose Type") {
    //alert("Please select Merchant type");
    $("#lbldrpT").append("Please choose Reseller!");
    flag = false;//To prevent the form from submitting.
}else{
     $("#lbldrpT").empty();
}

if ($("select[id*=drpI]").val() == "Choose Industry") {
    $("#lbldrpI").append("Please choose Industry!");
    flag = false;//To prevent the form from submitting.
}else{
    $("#lbldrpI").empty();
}

if ($("select[id*=drpC]").val() == "Choose Country") {
    $("#lbldrpC").append("Please choose Coutnry!");
    flag = false;//To prevent the form from submitting.
}else{
    $("#lbldrpC").empty();
}

$("select").change(function(){
   $("#lbl"+$(this).attr("id")).empty(); 
   // or you can use this
  // $(this).parent().find("label").empty();
   //second one is better option
})

if (!jQuery("#Merchant_Registration").valid()) {
    flag = false;
}

if(flag)
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

in your code you return on the first if condition, so it never goes to the next if else. so put a flag to know if something is wrong.

Comment: thank you, it worked...the scenario now is like this:
when i click next, the page only shows the validation for the drop down lists...not the textboxes...how can i resolve that..?

Comment: i dont know which plugin you are using for validation. if you can let me know that, i could help you.

Comment: these are all of the plug ins that i am using:  <br/>
>!  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  <br/>  
>!  <script src="Scripts/plugins/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>  <br/>  
>!  <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>  <br/>
>!  <script src="Scripts/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

Comment: ok first of all you are using duplicate scripts please remove them. <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> is jquery version 1.9.1 and your plugin is using 1.7 so please see with which your plugin works. secondly <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script> and script src="Scripts/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js"> are same. second one is just the minified version of the first one so use either one of them.

Comment: the only script that i removed was <script src="Scripts/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js">..cause when i remove either 1.9.1 or 1.7.min.js..my design explodes...ahahahha...

Comment: i think your validator has some problem. i m not sure which validator you are using. may be u can paste a url for that plugin

Comment: hmmm...i tried something in my codes...its validates the dropdown and the textboxes, but the validation message for the drop down stays even if i chose an item in the drop down...

Comment: yeah, it worked..but what i like to do is:

when i click the next button without dropdown selection the message will be displayed, but the moment i selected something in the drop down list the error should disappear...not after clicking the next button..is it possible..?

Comment: ok i edit my answer again. i m not sure what version u r using for jquery. if .attr doesnt work then please use .prop

Comment: i encounterd another problem...ahahahah...this never ends...for example, i have supplied all the detail in the form except for one drop down list...when i clicked next, the error is displayed then it goes to the next page...

Comment: i posted my updated code...thank you very much for bearing with me...very much appreciated

Comment: i encountered another error...when i click the next button, the error for the drop down list appears, but it goes to the next page...

Comment: yes because you are already returning it when you check jQuery("#Merchant_Registration").valid(); replace your if condition with this `if (!jQuery("#Merchant_Registration").valid()) {
                        flag = false;
                    } `

Comment: i update my code above..and integrated what you said...but i still get the same error, it still moves to the next page..

Comment: yes it worked...but if remove the return true, the page is not permitted to submit even if all the controls has value...

Comment: you have return statement it checks for flag, if flag is true it ll submit. so if there is any error the flag ll become false and it will stop the submit.